# how to process a structure member inside a structure using JNA?

Tags: java, jna

I am working on JNA to return a nested structure pointer on a native function call. The nested structure has members of type unsigned char, struct. I was able to read the primitive types but struck up in processing the nested structure member e.g. OBISCODE in Response. My nested Structure looks like below:

```
typedef struct ObisCode
{
    unsigned char a;
    unsigned char b;
    unsigned char c;
    unsigned char d;
    unsigned char e;
    unsigned char f;
} OBISCODE;

typedef struct Response
{
    unsigned char result;
    OBISCODE obis;
} RESPONSE;
```

and native function as:

```
RESPONSE* getStruct(OBISCODE * obis)
```

My Java code calling this native function as below:

```
package struct;

    import com.sun.jna.Native;
    import com.sun.jna.Pointer;

public class JNATest {

    static {
        Native.register("StructTest"); 
    }


    public static class OBISCODE {
        private Pointer pointer;

        public OBISCODE() {
            long memory = Native.malloc(6);
            pointer = new Pointer(memory);
        }

        public OBISCODE(Pointer pointer) {
            this.pointer = pointer;         
        }

        Pointer getPointer() {
            return pointer;
        }

        int getA() {
            return pointer.getByte(0);
        }

        int getB() {
            return pointer.getByte(1);
        }

        int getC() {
            return pointer.getByte(2);
        }

        int getD() {
            return pointer.getByte(3);
        }

        int getE() {
            return pointer.getByte(4);
        }

        int getF() {
            return pointer.getByte(5);
        }

        void setA(byte a) {
            pointer.setByte(0, a);
        }

        void setB(byte b) {
            pointer.setByte(1, b);
        }

        void setC(byte c) {
            pointer.setByte(2, c);
        }

        void setD(byte d) {
            pointer.setByte(3, d);
        }
        void setE(byte e) {
            pointer.setByte(4, e);
        }
        void setF(byte f) {
            pointer.setByte(5, f);
        }

        void free() {
            Native.free(Pointer.nativeValue(pointer));
        }

    }


    public static native void printStruct(Pointer obis);

    public static native Pointer getStruct(Pointer obis);
    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {

            struct.JNATest.OBISCODE obis = new struct.JNATest.OBISCODE();
            obis.setA( (byte) 0);
            obis.setB( (byte)  0);
            obis.setC( (byte)  8);
            obis.setD( (byte)  0);
            obis.setE( (byte)  0);
            obis.setF( (byte)  255);

            Pointer ptr = obis.getPointer();
            System.out.println("ptr = " + ptr.toString());
            printStruct(obis.getPointer());

            Pointer resptr = getStruct(obis.getPointer());
            Response response = new Response(resptr);
            System.out.println("result = " + response.getResult());
            System.out.println("1=" + resptr.getInt(1) + "2=" + resptr.getInt(2)
                    );

            obis.free();

        } catch (UnsatisfiedLinkError e) {
            System.out.println("Exception" + e);
        }
    }
}
```

My equivalent native structure Response class as below

```
package struct;

import com.sun.jna.Native;
import com.sun.jna.Pointer;

public class Response {

    private Pointer pointer;

    public Response() {
        long memory = Native.malloc(6);
        pointer = new Pointer(memory);
    }

    public Response(Pointer pointer) {
        this.pointer = pointer;         
    }

    Pointer getPointer() {
        return pointer;
    }

    int getResult() {
        return pointer.getByte(0);
    }

    int getOBIS() {
        return pointer.getByte(1);
    }

    void setResult(byte a) {
        pointer.setByte(0, a);
    }

    void setOBIS(byte b) {
        pointer.setByte(1, b);
    }

    void free() {
        Native.free(Pointer.nativeValue(pointer));
    }

}
```

I was running this test in Redhat Linux  and the output obtained as below

```
result = 12
1=5242882=2048
```

Please correct me if I am missing something in Java code to process the structure. Any help is greatly appreciated? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

JNA provides direct support for [Structures](http://twall.github.io/jna/4.0/javadoc/com/sun/jna/Structure.html).

For example:

```
public class ObisCode extends Structure 
{
    public byte a;
    public byte b;
    public byte c;
    public byte d;
    public byte e;
    public byte f;
    protected List getFieldOrder() { return Arrays.asList(new String[] { "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f" }); }
    public OBISCODE() { }
    public OBISCODE(Pointer p) { super(p); read(); }
}

public class Response extends Structure
{
    public byte result;
    public OBISCODE obis;
    protected List getFieldOrder() { return Arrays.asList(new String[] { "result", "obis" }); }
    public Response() { }
    public Response(Pointer p) { super(p); read(); }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response Technomage!!! I am specifically want to process the Response structure in Java. The native fucntion is returning a pointer to a structure and I am not sure how to handle it in Java. I have also tried defining the structure in the same way you have suggested and as per JNA tutorials.

Comment: See `Structure(Pointer)`.  Either return the structure type directly, or return a pointer and initialize the structure yourself.